# API Key not found in Google Translate application

Tags: java, android, google-translate

I am trying to  use Google Translate  using this call method:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
Log.e("INFO",  "texttotranslate, from and to are:" + texttotranslate + ", " + from + " and " + to);
String key="MY_PERSONAL_API_KEY";
try {
    String encodedText = URLEncoder.encode(texttotranslate, "UTF-8");
    Log.e("INFO",  "encoded without troubles UTF-8");
    String urlStr = "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=" + key + "&q=" + encodedText + "&target=" + to + "&source=" + from;
    Log.e("INFO",  "called Google APIs correctly (I think)");
    URL url = new URL(urlStr);
    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    Log.e("INFO",  "opened httpsURLConnection correctly");
    InputStream stream;
    Log.e("INFO",  "input repsonse stream = "+conn.getResponseCode());
    if (conn.getResponseCode() == 200) //success
    {
        stream = conn.getInputStream();
        Log.e("INFO",  "gets input stream correctly");

    } else
        stream = conn.getErrorStream();
    Log.e("INFO",  "failed to get input stream correctly");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
    String line;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
        Log.e("INFO",  "line currently = " + line);
    }
```

I fail miserably, getting the following errors:

07-03 13:09:07.167 20916-21078/net.stuffilike.multitranslater E/INFO: encoded without troubles UTF-8
07-03 13:09:07.168 20916-21078/net.stuffilike.multitranslater E/INFO: called Google APIs correctly (I think)
07-03 13:09:07.179 20916-21078/net.stuffilike.multitranslater E/INFO: opened httpsURLConnection correctly
07-03 13:09:07.467 20916-21078/net.stuffilike.multitranslater E/INFO: input repsonse stream = 400
07-03 13:09:07.468 20916-21078/net.stuffilike.multitranslater E/INFO: failed to get input stream correctly
07-03 13:09:07.468 20916-21078/net.stuffilike.multitranslater E/INFO: line currently = {
07-03 13:09:07.468 20916-21078/net.stuffilike.multitranslater E/INFO: line currently =   "error": {
07-03 13:09:07.468 20916-21078/net.stuffilike.multitranslater E/INFO: line currently =     "code": 400,
07-03 13:09:07.469 20916-21078/net.stuffilike.multitranslater E/INFO: line currently =     "message": "API Key not found. Please pass a valid API key.",
07-03 13:09:07.469 20916-21078/net.stuffilike.multitranslater E/INFO: line currently =     "errors": [
07-03 13:09:07.469 20916-21078/net.stuffilike.multitranslater E/INFO: line currently =       {
07-03 13:09:07.469 20916-21078/net.stuffilike.multitranslater E/INFO: line currently =         "message": "API Key not found. Please pass a valid API key.",
07-03 13:09:07.469 20916-21078/net.stuffilike.multitranslater E/INFO: line currently =         "domain": "global",
07-03 13:09:07.469 20916-21078/net.stuffilike.multitranslater E/INFO: line currently =         "reason": "badRequest"
07-03 13:09:07.469 20916-21078/net.stuffilike.multitranslater E/INFO: line currently =       }
07-03 13:09:07.469 20916-21078/net.stuffilike.multitranslater E/INFO: line currently =     ],
07-03 13:09:07.469 20916-21078/net.stuffilike.multitranslater E/INFO: line currently =     "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
07-03 13:09:07.469 20916-21078/net.stuffilike.multitranslater E/INFO: line currently =   }
07-03 13:09:07.469 20916-21078/net.stuffilike.multitranslater E/INFO: line currently = }
07-03 13:09:07.498 20916-21078/net.stuffilike.multitranslater E/INFO: result = {  "error": {    "code": 400,    "message": "API Key not found. Please pass a valid API key.",    "errors": [      {        "message": "API Key not found. Please pass a valid API key.",        "domain": "global",        "reason": "badRequest"      }    ],    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"  }}

I have tried other API keys, but with the same result, suggesting to me something else is wrong here.  Can anyone offer me a valid thread to pull on here?

EDIT: depending on what I send as my string, I can get either the error which demands a valid API key, or a message that states my client has sent a malformed or illegal request.  Both types of request include the key.  Anybody seen this before?

Comment: Invalid API key, are you sure it's correct? Follow https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158862?hl=en to generate a new or use the native SDK: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java

Comment: I may be using the native SDK, since I cannot yet understand the flaw in my code or API key. : (
As far as I can tell the API key was generated correctly, has no restrictions on it, and is issued for the app.  What else can be wrong with the API key?

Comment: It's possible you aren't using/encoding the query string correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298897/how-to-pass-query-parameters-in-java-with-http-client

Comment: Tried that too; no change.  I UTF-8 encoded the key and the text, not the to language or the from language (es and en, respectively).

Comment: OK, I encoded the string fully assembled (excluding the to and from language abbreviations), and now I only have <p>Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>, which I can consider and improvement. : )

Comment: Ah!  Works if you only encode the text to translate. Thanks, Francisco Mateo!  I had tried to encode that plus the to and from language strings and the API key.  Not necessary.